# How to generate method with unknown parameters?

Tags: c#, code-generation

How to generate method with unknown parameters?

I use `Microsoft.CSharp.dll` to compile c# scripts:

```
 CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
 CompilerParameters compilerParams = new CompilerParameters { GenerateExecutable = false, GenerateInMemory = true };
 string scriptCode = GetFullCode(); //here i add usings and so on
 var results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParams, scriptCode);
```

So, I need to add some few functions, but this functions can be with any number of parameters and with list of types (`DateTime`,`int`,`double` and so on).

Function should be call like this:

```
function(String,String,DateTime,int,...);
```

or

```
function(DateTime,int,String,..);
```

and so on.

And user can use this functions in code.

How to generate this functions?
As example, I tell how I generate code now:

//GetFullCode:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (DictionaryEntry de in Assembles)
{
    foreach (var us in de.Value.ToString().Split(new char[] { ';' }))
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(us))
            sb.AppendLine("using " + us + ";");
    }
}

sb.AppendLine("namespace " + Namespace + "\n{");            
sb.AppendLine(GetClassCode());

if(withMainFunc)
{
    sb.AppendLine(@"static class Program
                    {

                    [STAThread]
                    static void Main()
                    { 
                        //some init code                                                       
                    }
                }");
}
sb.AppendLine("}");
```

Comment: Why do you want a undefined range of arguments, why not just parse a object with the given data? Then you are able to work on the attributes in the object...

Comment: @MartinM `string.Join()` or `string.Concat()` have this behaviour and they have their eligibility to exist

Answer (score 5):

Here is one approach with a variable amount of parameters

```
public static string funcion(params object[] Items)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var item in Items)
    {
        sb.Append(item);
    }
    return sb.ToString(); ;
}
```

This adds all given values into one string.

useage: `string Result = funcion(DateTime.Now, "foo", 1);`

Comment: @fubo, i try to use your code as soon as possible. Looks good:)

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted... Perhaps it was before the edit?